# Error: type '() => Map<String, dynamic>?' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?'

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

I am trying to get a barcode to scan an item and retrieve the item from cloud firestore database. The application is meant to then display the item onto the homepage.
But i keep having the same error.
I have tried to change it to Map<Dynamic, Dynamic>. I have also tried to remove it from not being null Map<String, dynamic> no question mark. All flutter lib are up to date as well as the pubspec.

The code below is for my homepage

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_barcode_scanner/flutter_barcode_scanner.dart';

  Map<String, dynamic>? mapProducts = {};

  //Initialize
  @override
  void initState() {
    if (userProfile.containsKey("Unordered Products")) {
      mapProducts = userProfile["Unordered Products"];
    }

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double size =
        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width < MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
            ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
            : (!kIsWeb)
                ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.height
                : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2;

    //For Refreshing the theme
    if (userProfile.containsKey("Theme")) {
      myAppTheme = userProfile["Theme"] == "Light Theme"
          ? getMainThemeWithBrightness(context, Brightness.light)
          : getMainThemeWithBrightness(context, Brightness.dark);
    }

    MobileScannerController cameraController = MobileScannerController();

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        key: scaffoldKey,
        backgroundColor: myAppTheme?.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        appBar: getAppBar(
          scaffoldKey: scaffoldKey,
          context: context,
          strAppBarTitle: "Spar Store",
          showBackButton: false,
        ),

        //drawer
        drawer: getDrawer(context, scaffoldKey),

        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          backgroundColor: myAppTheme?.primaryColor,
          onPressed: () async {
            String? barcode = await scan();
            if (barcode != null && barcode != "") {
              if (mapProducts!.containsKey(barcode)) {
                //Increase count
                setState(() {
                  mapProducts![barcode] = ++mapProducts![barcode];
                });
              } else {
                //Add a new product
                setState(() {
                  mapProducts![barcode] = 1;
                });
              }
              userProfile["Unordered Products"] = mapProducts;

              //Update the new Unordered Products list to the Firebase CLoud Firestpre
              await authService.setData();
            }
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add, color: myAppTheme?.iconTheme.color),
        ),

        //Body
        body: mapProducts != null && mapProducts!.length > 0
            ? Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  //Products in Cart List
                  getUnorderedProducts(size),

                  //Final invoice
                  getInvoice(size),

                  //Checkout Button
                  getCheckoutButton(size),
                ],
              )
            : Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.asset(
                      "assets/images/empty-cart.png",
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "No Items Added.\nPlease Add items by scanning them",
                      style: myAppTheme?.textTheme.caption,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

  //Get the list of all the Orders still in Cart
  getUnorderedProducts(double size) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.7,
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: mapProducts!.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return FutureBuilder(
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.data == null || snapshot.hasData == false) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                      valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                          myAppTheme!.primaryColor),
                      strokeWidth: 5,
                    ),
                  );
                } else {
                  Map<String, dynamic>? mapProduct = snapshot.data;

                  return GestureDetector(
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: myAppTheme?.cardTheme.elevation,
                      color: myAppTheme?.cardTheme.color,
                      shape: myAppTheme?.cardTheme.shape,
                      child: Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          mapProduct!.containsKey("photo url")
                              ? ClipRRect(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                      width: 120,
                                      child: Image.network(
                                          mapProduct["photo url"][0])))
                              : Icon(
                                  Icons.category,
                                  color: myAppTheme?.iconTheme.color,
                                ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: size - 150,
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                //Title
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    mapProduct["name"],
                                    style: myAppTheme?.textTheme.caption,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                  ),
                                ),

                                //Model
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Text(mapProduct["model"],
                                      style: myAppTheme?.textTheme.bodyText1,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.right),
                                ),

                                //Discount
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                      "Discount: ${mapProduct["discount"]}%",
                                      style: myAppTheme?.textTheme.bodyText1
                                          ?.copyWith(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.right),
                                ),

                                //Price
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Text("Price: ${mapProduct["price"]}",
                                      style: myAppTheme?.textTheme.bodyText1
                                          ?.copyWith(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.right),
                                ),

                                //Quantity
                                Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  height: 60,
                                  child: StepperTouch(
                                    initialValue:
                                        mapProducts?.values.elementAt(index),
                                    direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                    withSpring: true,
                                    primaryColor:
                                        myAppTheme?.colorScheme.secondary,
                                    textColor:
                                        myAppTheme?.textTheme.bodyText1?.color,
                                    onChanged: (int value) {
                                      if (value == 0) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          mapProducts?.remove(mapProducts?.keys
                                              .elementAt(index));
                                        });
                                      } else if (value > 0) {
                                        setState(() {
                                          mapProducts![mapProducts!.keys
                                              .elementAt(index)] = value;
                                        });
                                      }

                                      userProfile["Unordered Products"] =
                                          mapProducts;
                                    },
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),

                    //Open
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                ViewProductScreen(mapProduct)),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }
              },
              future: getProduct(mapProducts!.keys.elementAt(index)),
            );
          }),
    );
  }

  //Get the Total Price and the Total discount
  getInvoice(double size) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot == null ||
            snapshot.data == null ||
            snapshot.hasData == false) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              valueColor:
                  AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(myAppTheme!.primaryColor),
              strokeWidth: 5,
            ),
          );
        } else {
          Map mapProduct = snapshot.data;

          double dbTotalDiscount = mapProduct["discount"],
              dbTotalPrice = mapProduct["price"];

          return Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: <Widget>[
              
              //Total Price
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 10, 5),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Total Price:   ",
                      style: myAppTheme?.textTheme.bodyText1,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      dbTotalPrice.toString(),
                      style: myAppTheme?.textTheme.bodyText1,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
      },
      future: getInvoiceDetails(),
    );
  }

  getInvoiceDetails() async {
    double dbTotalDiscount = 0.0, dbTotalPrice = 0.0;

    //Loop through all the products to get the Discount and the Price
    await Future.forEach(mapProducts!.keys, (key) async {
      String strProductID = key;
      Map<String, dynamic>? mapProduct =
          (await getProduct(strProductID)) as Map<String, dynamic>?;

      if (mapProduct!.containsKey("discount")) {
        dbTotalDiscount += double.tryParse(
            (mapProduct["discount"] * mapProducts![key]).toString())!;
      }
      if (mapProduct.containsKey("price")) {
        dbTotalPrice += double.tryParse(
            (mapProduct["price"] * mapProducts![key]).toString())!;
      }
//      print("discount: " + dbTotalDiscount.toString());
//      print("price: " + dbTotalPrice.toString());
    });

    return {"discount": dbTotalDiscount, "price": dbTotalPrice};
  }

  //Get Checkout button
  getCheckoutButton(double size) {
    return ButtonTheme(
      minWidth: double.infinity,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(80, 20, 80, 10),
        child: primaryRaisedButton(
          context: context,
          text: "Checkout now",
          color: myAppTheme?.primaryColor,
          onPressed: () async {
            //Go to Checkout
            await Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CheckoutScreen()),
            );

            setState(() {
              //Refresh the UI after returning back from the Checkout screen
              mapProducts = userProfile["Unordered Products"];
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  //=================================================================================
  //Get details of product
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>? Function()> getProduct(String barcode) async {
    return (await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Products")
            .doc(barcode)
            .get())
        .data;
  }

  //Scan QR code
  Future<String?> scan() async {
    try {
      String barcode = (await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          '#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.QR));
      return barcode;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.cameraAccessDenied) {
        showSnackBar(
            scaffoldKey: scaffoldKey,
            text: "The user did not grant the camera permission!",
            buttonText: '',
            onPressed: () {});
      } else {
        showSnackBar(
            scaffoldKey: scaffoldKey,
            text: "Unknown error: $e",
            buttonText: '',
            onPressed: () {});
      }

      return null;
    } on FormatException {
      showSnackBar(
          scaffoldKey: scaffoldKey,
          text:
              'null (User returned using the "back"-button before scanning anything. Result)',
          buttonText: '',
          onPressed: () {});
    } catch (e) {
      showSnackBar(
          scaffoldKey: scaffoldKey,
          text: "Unknown error: $e",
          buttonText: '',
          onPressed: () {});
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

If anyone can help would be great as i am a beginner and it is for a school project.

Comment: it's too much code to analyze, can your exclude the code that's not related to the problem

Comment: first remove `Function()` part in the return type of `getProduct(String barcode)`that's most likely it. return type should be `Future<Map<String, dynamic>?>`

Comment: @Hydra it is giving me an error when i remove it. The error is: 
A value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>? Function()' can't be returned from the method 'getProduct' because it has a return type of 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>>'

Comment: It's better to make your question show only the minimum amount of code to understand the question, to keep it focused and to respect the time of the people you are asking help from. You're asking us to read through a lot of code before we can get to the part you're really asking about. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @joanis sorry, I will definitely do better next time. I just did not know which code to leave out as when I change the getProduct or Map I would get errors throughout the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

replace your `getProduct()` method with this:

```
 Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> getProduct(String barcode) async {
    return (await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Products")
            .doc(barcode)
            .get())
        .data() ;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @Gwhyyy but this code gives me an error. The error is from await saying: A value of type 'Map<String, dynamic>? Function()' can't be returned from the method 'getProduct' because it has a return type of 'Future<Map<String, dynamic>?>'   Your previous suggestion worked more than anything but came with an error of: CastError (type '_JsonDocumentSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' in type cast)